# I build screencap myself,but it doesn't work

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I have built followed [AOSP DOCUMENT](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).

```
export OUT_DIR_COMMON_BASE=~/aospout
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-user
make -j1
```

This build was successful.

but what i needed is the binary file "/aosp/target/product/generic/system/bin/screencap".
I copy it to my device.

```
shell@android:/data/data/hello-exe # chmod 777 screencap
chmod 777 screencap
shell@android:/data/data/hello-exe # ./screencap
./screencap
reloc_library[1306]: 26032 cannot locate '_ZN7android21SurfaceComposerClient17getBuiltInDisplayEi'...
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

I don't know why it happens.
Any suggestion?

Comment: screencap uses a non-public API, so you can't simply build it with the NDK.

Comment: Thanks to your reply.I think I have solved this.My device is 4.1,but I built screencap in aosp 4.4.